# Is there a way to generate a callback when an upload is completed successfully or failed with okhttp?

Tags: file, file-upload, callback, upload

**Goal**:
Knowing if an upload made with okttp4 on Android was successful or failed.
**Tried**:
Sending a query to the server after a certain amount of time. This is possibly not the optimal approach.
**Code**:

```
var url = HttpUrl.Builder()
    .scheme("http")
    .host(ConstantValues.HOST)
    .port(ConstantValues.PORT)
    .addPathSegment(relativeUrl)
    .addQueryParameter("fileName", "expectedFileSize")
    .build()

val request = Request.Builder()
    .url(url)
    .get().build()

val client = OkHttpClient()

client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
    override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: java.io.IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }

    override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
        if (response.isSuccessful) {
            val result: String = response.body?.string() ?: "failed"
            checkSizesMatch(result)
        }
    }
})
```

This is ok for our needs. Is there a direct way to accomplish this without making a specific query to the server?
Is there a callback that can tell me if the file was fully uploaded successfull?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found is to use

`CountingRequestBody`

> Decorates an OkHttp request body to count the number of bytes written when writing it. Can
>    decorate any request body, but is most useful for tracking the upload progress of large
>    multipart requests.

It lets the app monitor the upload activity.
This way you can tell how much time it is taking and when it is complete without sending a query to the server to monitor this process.